# How to reactivate ruler controls (tabs, indents) in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

For some unknown reason the controls in the ruler turned hidden/deactivated.
Like this:

[image: Screenshot]

They were on, now they're gone. And I see no option anywhere.

How can I reactivate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we ran some tests. It turns out that due to size of our document (some 150 pages, 35MB) the rendering of the controls fails for some reason. They are however still active. You are just left to work with invisible icons. 
The best solution we could come up with so far is:

1) close all word documents
2) open the Word app and create a blank document
3) Leave it that way and then open the big document over it
All the controls should appear normally then.

Answer (score 2):

Check the **View** ribbon. There are several options to decide how you'd like the window/document to appear (sorry, I only have the German UI language available; but you should be able to find the options):

[image: Word's View ribbon (Word 2013)]

Comment: Check [here](http://0.tqn.com/d/presentationsoft/1/0/l/5/-/-/16view_ribbon.jpg) for the english language equivalent.

Comment: This is not the problem at all. ruler was displayed, the controls in it were not.

Comment: Ah, so the tab pips, border markers, etc.? You should remove your suggestions from your initial post and put them in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Select File > Options
Click Display in the navigation pane on the left hand side.
If the "Show white space between pages in Print Layout view" check box is clear, tick it.
Click OK.

Answer (score -1):

One way to fix problem is go to Desktop, right click, select Personalize and just choose another theme.  Magically the tabs and margins will now appear in Word doc.  Can't believe that Microsoft hasn't fixed this obvious glitch.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is here

### Step 1

Choose View and Check the Ruler check box.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-or-hide-the-rulers-dc8a4e0d-209f-43b8-b967-8e65da24d4c7

### Step 2

In Word 2010, 2013, or 2016:

On the View tab, in the Views group, click Print Layout.
Click Print Layout
On the File tab, click Options > Display.
Under Page display options, select the Show white space between pages in Print Layout view check box.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/My-top-margin-is-missing-993773e9-4be6-44ae-b9ab-7e0a5d2b8298

Comment: You need to quote and cite the relevant information from your answer.  If those links were to stop working, your other content by itself, does not appear to answer the question.  I also can't tell what you have said yourself and what you are citing, quote blocks exist for a reason, use them.